# Monty Hall and a Mendelian F1 monohybrid cross

Tags: probability, genetics

I'm reading a biology textbook and I also happen to have read the Monty Hall Problem article on Wikipedia recently. I'm a middle aged layperson. (Been a long time since anyone's taught me anything so my reasoning is suspect.)

> A mating between two carriers corre sponds to a Mendelian F₁ monohybrid cross, so the predicted genotypic ratio for the off spring is 1 AA: 2 Aa:1 aa. Thus, each child has a 1/4 chance of inheriting a double dose of the recessive allele; in the case of albinism, such a child will have albinism. From the genotypic ratio, we also can see that out of three offspring with the normal phenotype (one AA plus two Aa), two are predicted to be heterozygous carriers, 2/3 chance.

1. Is this a variation on the Monty Hall problem?
2. Is the book correct? (Not sure I even understand the Monty Hall problem.)

It seems to me that knowing the outcome of one member of the F2 generation wouldn't change the probabilities for the remaining children.

Comment: There isn't any question in the quotation, which makes it difficult to compare to the Monty Hall problem.  The quotation is an example of a *Binomial distribution.*  The second part of the quotation is an example of a *conditional distribution.*

Comment: I thought that knowing that the three children weren't albino was like revealing door number four was albino. And since, in the Monty Hall problem the unintuitive reason you should switch, is that the probability of the remaining doors hadn't changed. I don't understand why the probability of a homozygous dominant child goes from 1/4 to 1/3 just because you know that two others were also phenotypically the same??

But I also kind of don't understand the articles about binomial and conditional distribution, so I think I asked a silly question.

Comment: Ugh. What they're saying is trivial. This section has a lot of over-explaining as if to address any possible misconception. They seemed to be talking about a family with four kids. Each of the four kids had 1:2:1 probabilities which means there's some probability of having all albino kids. However, they're using a family as an illustration of a population, which is not a good choice in my opinion. This whole section has been like that.